# How do you find where the rsync process is coming from?

Tags: rsync

How do you find where the rsync process is coming from? We have a rsync process, but I am not sure what's the thing that initiate it. I looked at our cronjob running from the Wordpress project, looked at the code, and I don't really see anything that might be running it, but I know it's there, because I think I ran iotop and saw it. What are some helpful commands that would allow me to find it?

Comment: `ps` shows the parent processes. It can also show the process tree with `--forest`.

Comment: On what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pstree`. First, get the PID of the process (you should be able to see it in `iotop`) and then you can run:

```
$ pstree -p 2346372
rsync(2346372)───rsync(2346373)───rsync(2346374)
```

That gives the process tree of the process with PID `2346374`. The numbers in parentheses are the PIDs of the various processes in the tree.